# как сделать поиск на php?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Есть бд с названием products. В ней содержаться id, name, description, count, price, image, type. И мне нужно сделать поиск по ключевому слово name.

P.S Скинул бы кусок кода, но у меня и этого даже нету, в первые работаю с поисковиками пытался гуглить находил похожие, но при копировании кода (если что я его менял) ничего не получалось

Comment: SELECT * FROM products WHERE name='что ищем'

Comment: [SQL Оператор LIKE](https://schoolsw3.com/sql/sql_like.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотря какой поиск..
С клиента ajax'ом раз в некоторое время(когда юзер перестал печатать, например) передаешь в обработчик данные из поисковой строки.

P.S. - Скопировать не получится, придется почитать.

Обработчик (примерно)

```
$pdo = new pdo (..)
$param = "%апельсин%"; //Соответственно вместо апельсин - данные из ajax
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM products WHERE name LIKE ?");
$query->execute([$param]);
// дальше обработка и формирование ответа
```

Если без динамики, то

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM products WHERE name=?");
$query->execute(['то, что ищем']);
```

Если через mysqli, то сначала экранируешь, потом ищешь.

Comment: чего вы хотите экранировать в mysqli ? там тоже параметры можно передавать. зы: `*` использовать - плохой тон

Comment: @teran Люблю экранировать. Лишним не бывает. Почему `*` - плохой тон ? Хочу выбрать всё. Буду каждую колонку переписывать ? а зачем ?

Comment: потому что смена порядка столбцов в таблице может сломать код, если вы выбираете не ассоциативный, а индексированный массив. выборка большого числа столбцов может замедлить запрос, а если в какой-то момент в таблицу попадут большие поля бинарные например, то это вообще станет подвешивать все. В целом возрастет нагрузка на сеть, ненужная. так же при указании звездочки сервер тратит некоторое время на то, чтобы обратиться к схеме данных и таки выяснить, какие поля надо выбрать. так что в целом, * если и используется, то разве что с оператором exist, там формальная выборка не проводится.